# How to convert a single letter of a string toLowerCase

Tags: string, stringbuilder, lowercase

I would like to find a way to only convert a specific character of a string to lower case.

Using a loop as I want it to be dynamic I tried the following:

For example in this case, I want that for whatever word I input only "A" characters will be put to lower case.

```
         String word = new String("YehAAA");
         String word2 = new String();

         int n;


         for (int i =0;i<word.length();i++){

         n = word.indexOf('A');
         word2 = word.substring(0,n)+'a'+word.substring(n+1);

         }
```

I have a feeling that the issue lies in the fact that strings can't be changed, that is why I had to create a new one. However it only works once, there after I will need x amount of new strings. If this is the case I will have to learn about StringBuilder, I just want to make sure that my intuition is right, if not I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = new String("YehAAA");

//Convert string to char array.
char[] word2 = word.toCharArray();


for(int i = 0;i<word2.length;i++)
{
     if(word2[i] == `A')
     {
        word2[i] = 'a';
     }      
}

//convert char array to String.
String word3 = String.valueOf(word2);

System.out.println(word3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# i can write this way

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter example strings: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter character you want converted to lower case: ");
            var charToConvert = Console.ReadKey();
            string result = "";
            foreach (char charter in input)

            {
                if (char.ToLower(charter) == char.ToLower(charToConvert.KeyChar))
                    result += char.ToLower(charter);
                else
                    result += charter;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

output:

[image]